# How to file a bug report against Ubuntu in general?

Tags: security, hash

I am wanting to file a bug report against Ubuntu in general, because I have noticed that the [Ubuntu security hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) provided, are only MD5sums, and as for security reasons MD5 is being phased out, it seems ridiculous to have only MD5sums listed there, if the main reason for checking them is security reasons. It would be far better to use SHA256, or at least to give both, as the problems noticed in MD5, have not been noticed as present in SHA256.

Anyway, I want to complain about this, so I am wanting to file a pug report, but not sure exactly how to do this, because ideally I would file it against Ubuntu generally [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu), but if I click on the report bug button I just get redirected to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) page, which just tells me to use apport, but in apport it doesn't let you not selected a specific package, so I am really lost on how I am going to file this report, and where I am going to file it...

So I thought that I should ask a question about it here, so, how and where do I file this report? Or complain in some way?

Comment: The purpose of listing the MD5 hashes of the ISOs is to allow the user to check for the ISO integrity, the fact that a colliding file might be generated by an attacker (leaving aside the fact that colliding files may theoretically be generated with preimage attacks, which are *very* slow) is irrelevant; using MD5 to check for files integrity it's safe: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link to the appropriate bugs page right there on the wiki page. Just click on the link, and then on the resulting Ubuntu-docs bugs page click on the "Report a bug" link in the upper right corner of the page. You should end up [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+filebug). You will need to have a launchpad account.

Note that there is controversy over that particular wiki page because it falls under the purview the Ubuntu-docs group, but that group is not the master of the checksums.

EDIT: By the way, there is already [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1288593). You can just add your comment to it.

Comment: Which group is master of the checksums then?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda presumably https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage?